# Inconsistency in Safari 14.1 localStorage

Tags: javascript, safari, local-storage

`Safari 14.1` is not allowing to access `localStorage` items that have been set from a different browser tab. It is not even listing the `localStorage` items that are set from other browser tabs and behaving just like a `sessionStorage`.

Could find this bug raised here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=225344 but no information like when this would be rolled out.

One of our core features in my application is purely based on `localStorage` and it is now completely blocked due to this issue. My clients mainly use Safari.

Is anyone facing a similar issue and working on any workarounds?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The last comment in the bug page says it's fixed in MacOS 11.5.

Comment: Another comment there suggests using indexedDB and service workers as the workaround.